# PostgreSQL - Which JOIN to use?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Which JOIN do I use to answer this question?

[image: Preview]

[image: Preview]

What query would I write to find out what CBSA each customer belonged to? Whenever I try and JOIN on zip and `postal_code` I get duplicate id's. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If ZIP is unique on the second table you shouldn't be getting duplicates. Perhaps post your query, then take a look at one of the duplicates in detail and confirm whether or not the ZIP is unique in the table

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Check the zip codes. Contrary to popular believe zip codes are **not unique** for city, county, even state. There are at least 13 zip codes that cross state lines. And one, 57717, that at one time included parts of 3 states (MT, SD, WY). I think that has changes but who knows that the USPS might do. If that is your issue you will need some other method of getting unique values.  Perhaps zip+state+country.

Comment: What QUERY would you use to find out what CBSA each customer belonged to?  Let me try what you think it should be and see if it works...

Comment: The query is fine. The issue is for example: when a postcode is 57717, should the state be MT,SD,WY? Which one?